# How to unlock the blockage introduced by a queue?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, queue, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am running the following Python script (only shown the main part here) without any problem, and getting the execution of both models (model1 and model2) simultaneously: [the call to model just print the name of the model]

```
      from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
      <....>
      with tf.Session() as sess:
          with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 100) as executor:
              a = executor.submit(model1())
              b = executor.submit(model2())
```

Now, I want to connect both processes using a queue, for which I modified the script as:

```
      with tf.Session() as sess:
          q = Queue()
          with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 100) as executor:
              a = executor.submit(model1(q))
              b = executor.submit(model2(q))
```

In this case, I observe that model1 is executing but model2 is blocked. Only if I stop the ongoing execution, I observe the printing made by model2. Also, when I place in the script model2 before model1, the execution shows me the printings of model2, and when stopping the execution it appears the printings of model 1. Thus, it seems there is a sort of blockage introduced by the use of a queue.

How can I disable that blocking effect to get parallel execution of both models?

I would appreciate comments on how to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Did you mean: executor.submit(model1) and later: executor.submit(model1, q). ?

Comment: @quamrana: I tested the way you suggested. However, I am getting the same problem as I described. In any case, I can define executor.submit(model1, q)  OR executor.submit(model1(q)) in my script, and in both ways getting the same problem.

Comment: But, you do understand now why `executor.submit(model1())` is wrong?

Comment: @quamrana: perhaps I am not getting those you are saying but for the concurrent execution of model1 and model2 that syntaxis work just fine in my case (i.e. executor.submit(model1()) and executor.submit(model2())). I mean, I get the parallel execution of both models. BTW, I also tested writing it as, for example executor.submit(model1), and later adding the queues as paramenter or as executor.submit(model1, q). I get the problem of blockage only when adding the queue. If I am not getting those you are saying, please develop a little bit more your point. Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question with a sample implementation of `def model1():`